# Recover public key from sign generated by AWS Cloud HSM - Golang

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, ecrecover

I am signing a transaction by using a private key in AWS Cloud HSM. But not able to recover the correct public key from the signature. Every time I try to run **ECRecover** method, it generates different public key.

I am able to retrieve the R and S from ECDSA signature generated by AWS Cloud HSM in the following code:

```golang
import (
  "github.com/btcsuite/btcd/btcec"
  ethcrypto "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
)
// SignatureValues returns signature values [R || S]
func (e *Ethereum) SignatureValues(sig []byte) (r, s *big.Int, err error) {
    r = new(big.Int).SetBytes(sig[:32])
    s = new(big.Int).SetBytes(sig[32:64])
    return r, s, nil
}
```

And below code snippet tries to find the correct signature to be verified:

```golang
    sig := make([]byte, 65)

    denTwo := big.NewInt(2)
    rightS := big.NewInt(0)
    curve := btcec.S256()

    /*
        URL: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-2.md
        All transaction signatures whose s-value is greater than secp256k1n/2 are now considered invalid.
        The ECDSA recover precompiled contract remains unchanged and will keep accepting high s-values; this is useful
        e.g. if a contract recovers old Bitcoin signatures.
    */
    rightS = rightS.Div(curve.Params().N, denTwo)

    if rightS.Cmp(S) == -1 {
        S = S.Sub(curve.Params().N, S)
        log.Println("S: ", S.String())
        rbytes, sbytes := R.Bytes(), S.Bytes()
        copy(sig[32-len(rbytes):32], rbytes)
        copy(sig[64-len(sbytes):64], sbytes)
        log.Println("Result : ", verifyECRecover(hash.Bytes(), sig, expectedPubKey))
    } else {
        rbytes, sbytes := R.Bytes(), S.Bytes()
        copy(sig[32-len(rbytes):32], rbytes)
        copy(sig[64-len(sbytes):64], sbytes)
        log.Println("Else Result : ", verifyECRecover(hash.Bytes(), sig, expectedPubKey))
    }

    verification := ethcrypto.VerifySignature(expectedPubKey, hash.Bytes(), sig)
```

Below code method is VerifyECRecover:

```golang
func verifyECRecover(hash, sig, expectedPubKey []byte) bool {
    for v := 0; v < 2; v++ {
        sig[64] = byte(v)
        if pubkey, err := ethcrypto.Ecrecover(hash, sig); err == nil {
            if bytes.Equal(pubkey, expectedPubKey) {
                log.Println("Matched")
                return true
            }
            log.Println("Not Matched")
        } else {
            log.Println("Error: ", err)
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I am not able to get the correct public key, so that I can submit the transaction to ethereum blockchain. Can anyone help me in solving this?

Comment: It works well if I sign the transaction without AWS Cloud HSM and size of sign is also of 65 bytes (64 + 1 recovery id). Cloud HSM generates the ECDSA signature with larger S value (S > Curve.N/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the issue and writing the answer to help anyone who face similar issue.

The issue was due to incorrect use of asn object identifier for secp256k1 which is 1.3.132.0.10. Reference URL: [secp256k1 ASN Object ID](http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.132.0.10).

Using this OID has resulted in retrieving the correct public key and I am able to transmit transaction to Ethereum blockchain now. It is implemented using Golang through PKCS11 specification.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on this? Which part of your code did you fix to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this issue while using localstack kms. It is because asymmetric keys are not supported well, as per this thread: https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/7311